# Dynamic sql to select a specific value from a column using Joins

Tags: t-sql, dynamic-sql

I am attempting to use dynamic sql to select a value based on a field. I have a table of field references I am using for the column names. What I am having troubles with is of course the dynamic sql. My return result is `(SELECT ecoa_code FROM CRA_METRO2_BASE WHERE id = 568470)` for example. But I really want it to run that select statement. Executing only returns the last row.

```
DECLARE @BaseCol VARCHAR(250)
SELECT 
   @BaseCol = '(SELECT ' + FR_base.field_name + ' FROM CRA_METRO2_BASE WHERE id = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), B.id) + ')'
FROM CRA_INNOVIS_AUDIT_ERROR_FIELDS E
LEFT JOIN CRA_METRO2_BASE B
    ON B.id = E.base_id
LEFT JOIN CRA_METRO2_FIELD_REF FR_base
    ON FR_base.id = E.base_field_ref
WHERE E.audit_id = @audit_id

EXEC(@BaseCol)
```

Comment: Cannot be done like that.  You don't even know it is a valid column name. It could change row to row.

Comment: Except I am joining it to my Field_Ref table, which will have the field I am selecting for. Editing the post now.

Comment: No, that table will not have the field. That table will have some text (char, varchar) - there is no data type of column.   The query optimizer cannot use the output from any query to build the query.

Comment: Yes, it will have the text of the column name. Is there a way to execute that row it produces? Or is there a better route I can take.

Comment: You could go to MSDN and learn how dynamic sql works.  Right now you are just using the word.

Comment: Edited the above post. Trying to learn my friend.

Comment: Well does it work?

Comment: Returns my last row only. So, not completely. I will be attempting to get it to return x amount of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I used my above query and now I am using a CTE to build my basic result list. And in my cte I create update statements which then are all put into a temp table.
I extract the update statements and execute them on the temp table. And walla, I have my results!

```
IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #Temp
    END

    CREATE TABLE #Temp
    (
        usb_data VARCHAR(500), 
        cra_data VARCHAR(500)
    );

    WITH ErrorFieldsCTE(id, field, usb_data, cra_data, AUD, SOR, acceptable_variance, is_variance_known, is_reviewed)
    AS(
        SELECT 
            + 'UPDATE #TEMP SET usb_data = (SELECT ' + FR_base.field_name +' FROM CRA_METRO2_BASE WHERE id = '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), B.id) +' ) WHERE id = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), E.id) + ' ' [usb_data],
            + 'UPDATE #TEMP SET cra_data = (SELECT ' + FR_audit.field_name +' FROM CRA_INNOVIS_INBOUND_AUDIT_INFORMATION WHERE id = '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), A.id) +') WHERE id = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), E.id) + ' ' [cra_data]
        FROM CRA_INNOVIS_AUDIT_ERROR_FIELDS E
        LEFT JOIN CRA_METRO2_BASE B
            ON B.id = E.base_id
        LEFT JOIN CRA_INNOVIS_INBOUND_AUDIT_INFORMATION A
            ON A.id = E.audit_id
        LEFT JOIN CRA_METRO2_FIELD_REF FR_audit
            ON FR_audit.id = E.audit_field_ref
        LEFT JOIN CRA_METRO2_FIELD_REF FR_base
            ON FR_base.id = E.base_field_ref
        WHERE E.audit_id = @audit_id
    )

    INSERT INTO #Temp
    SELECT 
        id, field, usb_data, cra_data, AUD, SOR, acceptable_variance, is_variance_known, is_reviewed
    FROM ErrorFieldsCTE

    SELECT -- extract query
        @usb_data += usb_data + '',
        @cra_data += cra_data + '' 
    FROM #Temp

    EXEC(@usb_data) -- updating temp table, selects usb-data
    EXEC(@cra_data) -- updating temp table, selects cra-data

    SELECT  -- return to web
        id, field, usb_data, cra_data, AUD, SOR, acceptable_variance, is_variance_known, is_reviewed
    FROM #Temp

    IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL)
    Begin
        Drop Table #Temp
    End
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your premises correctly and without a mock-up...; so please take this answer with a grain of salt:)

```
DECLARE @sqlstring VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @sqlstring = 'SELECT ' + a.column_name + ' FROM ' + a.[Schema] + '.' + a.table_name
from (
SELECT TOP 1 T.object_id,OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(T.[object_id],DB_ID()) AS [Schema],   
    T.[name] AS [table_name], AC.[name] AS [column_name]   
    --,TY.[name] AS system_data_type
    , AC.[max_length],  
    AC.[precision], AC.[scale], AC.[is_nullable], AC.[is_ansi_padded]  
    ,AC.column_id
FROM sys.tables AS T   
INNER JOIN sys.[all_columns] AC ON T.[object_id] = AC.[object_id]
) a
SELECT @sqlstring
EXEC(@sqlstring)
```